# Skip-free random walks: recurrence and transience

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walks

Let us define a one dimensional random walk: for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$
X_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i
$$
with $Z_i$ i.i.d. random variables taking values in $\{-1,0,1,2,\dots\}$. This process is sometimes called a *skip-free random walk*. Let
$$
\tau_{-1}:=\inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}: X_n=-1\}.
$$
How can one prove that
$$
\mathbb{E}[\tau_{-1}]<\infty$$
*if and only if* $\mathbb{E}[Z_1]<0$? Is there an easy way to see this as an exercise? I could not find anything in literature, although it seems that this result is cited several times. Maybe it is just an easy extension of known proofs for nearest neighbour one dimensional random walk, but I could not figure out how. Thanks a lot in advance for helping!

Comment: If $Z_i$ attains values $\pm1$ with probabilities $1/2$, isn't $\mathsf E[\tau_{-1}]$ finite? Do you want a non-strict inequality, or otherwise do you wish $Z_i$ to attain *all* values in $\{-1,0,1,\dots\}$?

Comment: No, in this case the expectation is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  One direction is easy, if $E(Z_1) < 0$ then $\frac{X_n}n \rightarrow E(Z_1)$, and it's pretty easy to see that it can't do that if $E(\tau_1 ) = \infty$.   For the other, suppose $E(\tau_1) < \infty$ . The apply Wald's identity,  disposing of the case $E(Z_1) = \infty$ first, which read $-1 = E(\tau_1)E(Z_1)$,

Comment: But $\tau_{-1}$ is not independent from the $Z_i$ --- can you apply the identity?

Comment: Yes, it is not important that it be independent, only that it be a stopping, which it is.  A couple of asides:  I call these random walks 'left continuous', which I think is a term I picked up from spitzer's book, and 2.  if you find this question engaging you might enjoy the section and ladder height variables, time reversal and related topics in Feller Vol 2

Comment: My concern is just the same I expressed in a comment to the original post: if $Z)i$ is concentrated on $\{-1,1\}$ with the zero mean, it seems that the expectation of $\tau_{-1}$ is finite...

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov  It is classical that this expectation is infinite.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone!